# Value-initialization of class containing std::queue

Tags: c++, gcc, queue, c++14

Here is a MCVE:

```
#include <queue>

struct S
{
    std::queue<int> q;
    int r;
};

int main()
{
    S s{};
}
```

With gcc 6.x `-std=c++14 -pedantic` I get warnings

```
<source>:11:9: warning: converting to 'std::queue<int>' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::queue(_Sequence&&) [with _Tp = int; _Sequence = std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >]'
 S s{};
     ^
<source>:11:9: note: in C++11 and above a default constructor can be explicit            ^
```

In gcc 7.x, or clang , there are no warnings.

My question is: Is this code actually correct or not; and if it is correct, what are the warnings trying to warn me about exactly?

Comment: As a workaround for GCC 6 I used `std::queue<int> q{};` inside the S

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is, in fact, ill-formed under the standard as published, which depicts `queue` with an explicit default constructor.

`S` is an aggregate; `S s{};` is aggregate initialization and doesn't call the default constructor of `S`. Instead, since no explicit initializer is specified for `q`, it's copy-initialized from an empty initializer list, which is ill-formed because copy-list-initialization selected an explicit constructor.

GCC 7 gave `queue` a non-explicit default constructor (which is how it should be anyway), which is why you aren't seeing the error. Similarly, the default constructor of libc++'s `queue` has always been non-explicit.

Comment: Is this `explicit` constructor business a defect already, or should it be reported as such? Because I'm fairly sure that it was not the intent of C++11 to break code in this way.

Comment: @Barry The point is that in C++03 the explicitness doesn't matter, but in 11 and later it does.

Comment: @T.C. Why doesn't it?

Comment: @Barry C++03 aggregate initialization simply value-initializes things that aren't explicitly initialized.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! space space

Comment: @NicolBolas I'll send something in some time this week. LWG did get rid of a bunch in C++14, I think, but it was mostly limited to containers with `initializer_list` constructors.